# 301 redirect rule for urls with dynamic paths

Tags: http-redirect

I'm on the learning curve for 301 redirects and have done lots of research, including looking at answers on this forum.  I haven't found the answer to my specific query, which requires removing elements from the middle of the url request.

Namely, I am building a new site with dynamic links (WordPress, but the question applies to any CMS).

I need to redirect from links (also dynamic) structured as:

sitename.com/issue/february-2016/post/*dynamic-post-name*
(february-2016 is an example - could be 'march-2014' or any of a range of terms)

to:
sitename.com/post/*dynamic-post-name*

Another way to say this: Any request url with /article/ needs to grab that last string (which I think would be the wildcard?) and redirect it as: sitename.com/post/$

Is this possible?

Update:  With more research, I found a possible answer that worked in a testing tool, although I've not tested it live on my site.

Does this look correct?

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/article/([^.]+)$ article/$3 [QSA,L]

Comment: Are you trying to do the redirection on the application (CMS) layer or server (web server) layer?

Comment: Ah good question - I'm doing this server layer in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^article/.*/(.*)$ post/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Something like this should work.

The characters captured within the brackets `(.*)` will be the `$1`.

Feel free to change `article` and `post` to fit your need.

In this case, it will redirect

`http://example.com/article/february-2016/post/dynamic-post-name`

to

`http://example.com/post/dynamic-post-name`

Comment: If the original structure is http://example.com/issue/february-2016/article/dynamic-post-name  ,   then would this be right:  RewriteRule ^.*/.*/article/(.*)$ article/$1 [QSA,L,R=301] ?

Comment: No. The first part is the search pattern, the latter is the replacement. You need to change `RewriteRule ^article` to `RewriteRule ^issue`.